# What is the difference between Boot volume and Block volume?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Do Boot volume refers to disk volume that contains the operating system files? What are the definitions for boot volume and block volume?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, in general boot volumes serve as the operating system disks for the compute instances, and block volumes as data storage, though boot volumes are also a type of block volumes.

Some differences:

- You don't need a block volume to start an instance, but you need a boot volume.
- Block volumes can be detached from running instances, boot volumes can't.

Some more details can be found in the [FAQs on block volumes](https://cloud.oracle.com/storage/block-volume/faq).